# Hey, I've been doing a discord bot and there was a problem, ts1005, any fixes?

Tags: bots, discord

I'm new to the visual studio code and I get this error, if I delete everything in this the error disappears ? I've been doing a discord bot and there is an error, 
Unreachable code detected.ts(7027)
'}' expected(ts1005)
index.js(18, 30) : The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.
can you guys help me or even send the correct for me?
The error is in the "bot.login(token);"(last) line

```
bot.on('message', message => {
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
switch (args[0]) {
  case 'pay':
    message.channel.send('no you')
    break;
  case 'info':
    if (args[1] == 'version') {
      message.channel.send('Version ' + version);
    } else {
      message.channel.send('you need to type something after this')
    }
    break;
  case 'clear':
    if (!args[1]) return message.reply('Error, type how much to clear!')
    message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
    break;
  case 'play':
    function play(connection, message) {
      var server = servers[message.guild.id];
      servers.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {
        filter: "audioonly"
      }));
      server.queue.shift();
      server.dispatcher.on("end", function() {
        if (server.queue[0]) {
          play(connection, message);
        } else {
          connection.disconnect();
        }
      });
    }
    if (!args[1]) {
      message.channel.send("you need to send a link!");
      return;
    }
    if (!message.member.voiceChannel) {
      message.channel.send("you must be in a voice channel!");
      return;
    }
    if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
      queue: []
    }
    var server = servers[message.guild.id];
    server.queue.push(args[1]);
    if (!message.member.voice.connection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection) {
      play(connection, message);
    })

    break;
    bot.login(token);
```

Comment: I edited your code since the indentation were wrong but I didn't touch your code. (`case` statements weren't indented on the same level).
From the new formatted code you can see that there are no closing tags for `bot.on('message', message => {` --> `})` is missing. Furthermore your `bot.login(token);` comes after `break` which means it'll never be executed. You have a Syntax mistake.

Comment: Run your code through a beautifier. You'll see the "blocks" of your code and from there you can determine where the `}` is missing. `switch (args[0]) {` this is also missing a closing `}`.

Comment: After running your code through a beautifier you want `bot.on()` and `bot.login()` to be on the same indentation level.

Comment: You make what you think would be correct, then you update your question with your new code as well as the new error message.